# How to copy 3 columns from one table into another in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables and both include 2 columns, sureness and kindness and and they are related to each other by dataitemID and id. Just to show you the structure I will put 2 selects that I got from database:

```
SELECT ID,sureness,kindness FROM omid.tweet  ;

SELECT ID,DataitemID,sureness,kindness FROM omid.entity_epoch_data ;
```

and I want to copy all value of sureness and kindness in omid.tweet into entity_epoch_data where entity_epoch_data.entityID is equal to entityID coming from entity_relation where tweet.ID =entity_relation.ID

I want just to do it in mysql rather than reading the whole table in java and updating the database in the loop but I am so confused. How can I do that?I appreciate any help:)

Update:

I wrote the code as follow but it does not  work:

```
update tweet, entity_epoch_data
set entity_epoch_data.sureness= tweet.sureness,
entity_epoch_data.kindness = tweet.kindness ,
entity_epoch_data.calmness = tweet.calmness ,
entity_epoch_data.happiness = tweet.happiness 
WHERE entity_epoch_data.EntityID in(
SELECT EntityID FROM omid.entity_dataitem_relation
INNER JOIN omid.tweet t ON entity_dataitem_relation.DataitemID = t.ID)
```

Comment: you need to either use a JOIN clause e.g. `tweet INNER JOIN entity_epoch_data ON tweet.id = entity_epoch_data.id ` or change your where clause to add the join. e.g. `WHERE  tweet.id = entity_epoch_data.id and entity_epoch_data.dataitemtype=3 and entity_epoch_data.EntityID =86`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty straight forward. The UPDATE clause works like a JOIN and then use SET to set the values

```
UPDATE tweet INNER JOIN entity_epoch_data
      ON tweet.id = entity_epoch_data.id    
SET entity_epoch_data.sureness= tweet.sureness,
    entity_epoch_data.kindness = tweet.kindness
```

Comment: Thanks a lot from you guidance I ran the code and understood that I need the updated situation above. Can you help me how  the update query for a bove scenario would look like?